# could not connect to ConsoleKit: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit': no such name

Tags: linux-mint, d-bus, consolekit

OS: Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit (which is based on Ubuntu 16.04)

In an effort to disable hibernation, I did the following with a consequence.

After I have moved the following polkit file to root directory with command:

```
sudo mv /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla /
```

and rebooted, the shutdown menu looks as follows:

[image: shutdown menu]

As you can see for yourself, there is no actual useful button. It starts to be annoying as I started shutting down my computer at night, which I do with logout menu button and from the login screen I click on shutdown.

Strange is, that after I re-created the file (I deleted it before I actually rebooted) makes no difference.

A few information...

```
ll /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

shows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 233 Oct 24 20:09 /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

and

```
cat /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

outputs:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

I checked with another machine with the same OS, and there is absolutely the same file.

I looked at the `history` and I am unaware, that I would do any other change than removing that one file. I am confused as to what destroyed my shutdown menu.

I am unsure, what went wrong, and what should I do now to get the standard shutdown menu back?

**EDIT1:**

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

revealed something:

```
Oct 24 20:56:56 vb-nb-mint cinnamon-session[1622]: WARNING: t+2496.50307s: Could not connect to ConsoleKit: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit': no such name
Oct 24 20:56:56 vb-nb-mint cinnamon-session[1622]: WARNING: t+2496.50368s: Could not connect to ConsoleKit: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit': no such name
Oct 24 20:59:50 vb-nb-mint cinnamon-session[1622]: WARNING: t+2670.11358s: Could not connect to ConsoleKit: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit': no such name
Oct 24 20:59:50 vb-nb-mint cinnamon-session[1622]: WARNING: t+2670.11426s: Could not connect to ConsoleKit: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit': no such name
```

The package `consolekit` is installed. Maybe corrupted?

```
apt-cache policy consolekit
```

shows:

```
consolekit:
  Installed: 0.4.6-5
  Candidate: 0.4.6-5
  Version table:
 *** 0.4.6-5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**EDIT2:**

I found out, that if I run:

```
ck-launch-session dbus-launch
```

the standard shutdown menu appears !!!

[image: after this command standard shutdown menu appears]

How do I make that command to run automatically with each boot?

**EDIT3:**

It is strange, though, that **Sleep** and Hibernate menu items are missing there. I highlight Sleep, because I would like to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution, looking back in the `history` again, there was:

> ```
> gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.session session-manager-uses-logind false
> ```

just above:

> ```
> sudo mv /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla /
> ```

I can only suppose I tried some guide on how to disable hibernation, and this was part of it.

So, the **solution** was to run the following command as normal user:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.session session-manager-uses-logind true
```

After reboot I can see the shutdown menu in a wanted state, **without** the need for running:

> ```
> ck-launch-session dbus-launch
> ```

[image: shutdown menu in a wanted state]